# From an array, group element if dates are consecutive in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, I'm trying to group elements if the date of each element are consecutive and if

- `NDC_Item`
- `NDC_Type`
- `NDC_Rate`
- `NDC_Taxes`
- `NDC_TaxesName`
- `NDC_Quantity`
- `NDC_Status`

are equal.

---

Actually the code I can test is the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-03-27
        [NDC_Item] => 0
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-03-28
        [NDC_Item] => 0
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-03-29
        [NDC_Item] => 0
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-03-30
        [NDC_Item] => 0
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-03-31
        [NDC_Item] => 0
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-01
        [NDC_Item] => 0
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [6] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-02
        [NDC_Item] => 0
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [7] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-03
        [NDC_Item] => 0
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
)
```

It's an array containing datas of a customer booking.

---

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $k = $item['NDC_Item'];

    if (!isset($result[$k])) {
        $result[$k] = $item;
    } elseif (
        ($i = $result[$k]) && 
        $item['NDC_Rate'] === $i['NDC_Rate'] && 
        $item['NDC_Type'] === $i['NDC_Type'] && 
        $item['NDC_Taxes'] === $i['NDC_Taxes'] && 
        $item['NDC_TaxesName'] === $i['NDC_TaxesName'] && 
        $item['NDC_Quantity'] === $i['NDC_Quantity'] &&
        $item['NDC_Status']=== $i['NDC_Status'] 
    ) {
        $current_dates = explode(', ', $result[$k]['NDC_Date']);
        $last_date = end($current_dates);
        if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$last_date} +1 day")) === $item['NDC_Date']) {
            $result[$k]['NDC_Id'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Id'];
            $result[$k]['NDC_Date'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Date'];
        } else {
            $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
        }
    } else {
        $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
    }
}
```

---

The problem is: actually, the previous code merge the first two elements (i.e.: 2017-03-27 and 2017-03-28 are grouped) but not 2017-03-29, 2017-03-30, ..., whereas it's consecutive...

---

The expected results should be:

```
Array (
    [Night] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-03-27,2017-03-28,2017-03-29,2017-03-30,2017-03-31,2017-04-01,2017-04-02,2017-04-03
        [NDC_Item] => 0
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 12.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
)
```

---

Any ideas why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did the array come from? Can you just create it as you need it?

Comment: Upvote for having well described your problem and test.

Comment: Firstly, should this `$k = $item['NDC_Item'];` not be `$k = $item['NDC_Type'];` ??

Comment: @Rob: you're right. I've correct the code. I voluntarily want to simplify the code but miss some parts. Thanks.

Comment: @F__M: thanks, I think it's the base of SO.

Comment: Your second mistake is that you're exploding the dates on `', '`, whereas you append the next date without a space between the comma and value. `$current_dates = explode(', ', $result[$k]['NDC_Date']);`, `$result[$k]['NDC_Date'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Date'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made two mistakes in your code.

1. `$k = $item['NDC_Item'];` should be `$k = $item['NDC_Type'];`
2. You're exploding the dates on `', '` (comma with following space). Whereas you're appending new dates with only a comma. `$current_dates = explode(', ', $result[$k]['NDC_Date']);` and `$result[$k]['NDC_Date'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Date'];`

[see this live demo](https://3v4l.org/j164H)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by #1, but #2 is completely right. was just figuring that out now - added my fiddle to your answer

Comment: The values in your `$result` array are indexed by the `NDC_Item` value. Whereas if you look at OPs desired output, the array should be indexed by the `NDC_Type` value.

Comment: nice, I didn't see that. fixed fiddle